# Getting the count of a mode of a list

Tags: simulation, netlogo

I am trying to get the value of a mode of a list. I know I can get the mode of a list by using the mode operator in a way such as "show modes [1 2 2 2 2 3 4]" which will report 2 as the mode, but how would I get the count for that mode, 4 in this case since their are 4 2's. I suppose I could get the mode and iterate through the list checking to see if each number is equal the mode, but I am just wondering if there is a simpler way.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A combination of `length` and `filter` should get you what you want:

```
let xs [1 2 2 3 3 4]
foreach modes xs [
  let mode ?
  let n length filter [ ? = mode ] xs
  print (word "mode: " mode ", occurrences: " n)
]
```

Will output:

```
mode: 2, occurrences: 2
mode: 3, occurrences: 2
```

(Of course, by definition, each mode will have the same number of occurrences.)

Comment: It took some deciphering using the Netlogo dictionary but I figured it out and the 4th line is mainly what I was looking for. Thanks for your help again Nicolas!